# How to generate a txt from CMD as dir/on/s however with the file name sorted from file extension

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I have created a file of a directory and it subdirectories with the command

```
dir/on/s>filename.txt
```

However this file shows the file names with the extension all together - e.g. `file-name-001.xlsx` or `file-drawing.pdf`.

It has been woeful to solve using Excel tools, so I was wondering if it is possible to create the file from cmd with the extension already in a separated column.

The current file extracted from txt, only misses the extensions in the yellow fields (I got those filled in the picture manually, but it has >35k lines)
[image: Excel-file-current] - notice that using dots as a criteria would cause trouble with some file names with dots in it. Also, xlsx, ods, sldprt have different numbers of characteres.

cmd where I extracted the txt and created the excel file above [image: cmd-1]

I tried the command

```
dir/on/s/-n
```

It got the file extension separated from file name (2nd column), however the file name is shorted with just a few characters; I need it with the full name of each file. [image: CMD-2].

Could you, please, inform if there are a better command in CMD for that (creating a txt with the extension separated from file names)?

Comment: Batch files do not write to the XLSX file format, _(they write in plain text)_, and have no concept of columns. You could however output your information to a CSV file, and use the field separators, to determine how that file may be formatted when imported into your XLSX viewing application.

Comment: Could you please also [edit] your question, to include a code formatted example of the content you want to have, in your resulting plain text file.

Comment: XLSX files are just zips containing XML files, so you could theoretically make an XLSX file if you hate yourself, but I strongly advise against it.

Comment: I would start by looking at using the `FOR` command which allows you to split up the file path, base file name and extension.

Comment: just pipe to a csv file.. here is an example from `cmd` to run similarly in a `batch-file` double up the `%` to `%%`. So.. `(@for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b/s/a-d') do @echo %~ti,%~ziKB,%i,%~xi,"%~dpi")>mycsv.csv`